# How do you set up the syntax for a random number generator using cpp?

Tags: c++, loops, random

Let me preface by saying I am very new to coding but enjoy learning. I want to randomly generate a number then follow with 700 if statements that will ask a question according to what number is generated. So from the user pov it will randomly ask questions and then will generate another number after.

I've tried the timing random number generators. I can't seem to get rand operator to work. I just want a super basic generator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a = "placeholder";
    cout << "Welcome to Basic Strategy Practice" << endl;
    cout << "You are given two aces and the dealer is showing a four. Hit, 
        double, or split ? " << endl;
        cin >> a;
    if (a == "split") {
        cout << "Correct!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Incorrect" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, I would encapsulate the above code in an if statement that specifies which number was generated after each question is asked. I would think you would just put the if statement inside a while loop of some sort. Thanks!

Comment: ***I can't seem to get rand operator to work***  You should have shown your code that used the random number. That would be a much better question for `StackOverflow` and its Q&A format.

Comment: Do you really expect the user to type in "split" or "double" or whatever, every time? They won't stick around for long! First, ask the to type a single letter by prompting for "[H]it, [D]ouble, or [S]plit". Then CHECK THE INPUT! If it is none of these three, go back and prompt the user again.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
#include <random>

int RandomBetween(int p_min, int p_max)
{
    static default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(p_min, p_max);
    return distribution(generator);
}
```

After that, you can call this function in a `switch`:

```
switch(RandomBetween(a, b))
{
    ...
}
```

If you want an example of a complete quiz program I made this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

std::string ToLower(std::string p_target)
{
    std::transform(p_target.begin(), p_target.end(), p_target.begin(), [](unsigned char c) { return std::tolower(c); });
    return p_target;
}

int RandomBetween(int p_min, int p_max)
{
    static std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(p_min, p_max);
    return distribution(generator);
}

class Question
{
public:
    Question(const std::string& p_message, const std::string& p_answer, bool p_caseSensitive) :
        m_message(p_message),
        m_answer(p_answer),
        m_caseSensitive(p_caseSensitive)
    {}

    std::tuple<bool, float> Ask() const
    {
        std::string answer;

        std::cout << m_message << std::endl;

        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
        start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::cin >> answer;
        end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

        return { answer == m_answer || (!m_caseSensitive && ToLower(answer) == ToLower(m_answer)), std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() / 1000.0f };
    }

private:
    std::string m_message;
    std::string m_answer;
    bool m_caseSensitive;
};

int main()
{
    bool gameRunning = true;
    std::vector<Question> questions;

    questions.emplace_back("Capital of France?", "Paris", false);
    questions.emplace_back("Is C++ object oriented? [Y/n]", "y", false);

    while (gameRunning)
    {
        const auto& [success, time] = questions[RandomBetween(0, 1)].Ask();

        std::string answerSpeed = "(Answered in: " + std::to_string(time) + "s)";
        if (success)
        {
            std::cout << "You are right!" << answerSpeed << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "You failed... Game is over!" << answerSpeed << std::endl;
            gameRunning = false;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Which can (Because it is a random game) outputs:

```
Capital of France?
Paris
You are right!(Answered in: 1.705000s)
Capital of France?
Paris
You are right!(Answered in: 2.368000s)
Capital of France?
Paris
You are right!(Answered in: 1.657000s)
Is C++ object oriented? [Y/n]
y
You are right!(Answered in: 3.927000s)
Capital of France?
I don't know
You failed... Game is over!(Answered in: 12.921000s)
```